# To check whether nohup service is running or not using shell script?

Tags: shell, nohup

I had created a nohup service using the below command in putty.

```
 nohup php /var/www/html/XYZ/sample.php &
```

This command executes the sample.php file in background.

Now what i need is i want a shell script which checks whether this service is running or not.Incase if the service is not running i want that shell script to create a service by its own. Below is the code what i tried.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    email_to="xyz@gmail.com";
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    PIDS=`ps -aux | grep sample.php|awk '{print $2}'`
    if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
       echo "$(date) - The service is not running. Sending email to :$email_to" >> /var/www/html/XYZ/sample.php;
       echo "SERVICE is not running - $(date)" | mail -s "service is not running - $(date)" $email_to
       echo "" >> /var/www/html/XYZ/sample.php;
       exit 1
    else
       echo "$(date) - Service already running.  Sending email to : $email_to" >> /var/www/html/XYZ/sample.php;
       echo "SERVICE is running - $(date)" | mail -s "SERVICE is  running - $(date)" $email_to
    fi
```

when i execute the file i get the mail as service is running ,and once i kill the sample.php and when i get execute this file i get the same mail "as service is running" but its wrong ,so can anyone direct me where have i gone wrong?

Comment: You should use a proper ["init script"](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html).

Comment: else use shell debug/trace `set -vx` (`set +vx` to turn off) to see what values are being used for `$PIDS` as the code executes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> where have i gone wrong?

With `ps -aux | grep sample.php`, the `grep` is finding `sample.php` in its own process command line `grep sample.php`, also output by `ps`. This can be avoided by modifying the grep command so that it doesn't contain `sample.php` literally, e. g. `grep 'sample\.php'` (which by the way averts the risk of matching another character instead of the `.`). You'll probably also need wide output from `ps` to not truncate the command, so change the above pipeline to `ps waux | grep 'sample\.php'`.